# Uploading image from Android to C# causes error and malformed image

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, bitmap, multipartform-data

I am trying to pick an image from a phone and upload it to a C# .Net Web service.
The mobile application is ok connecting to other .Net service components.

When I try to upload a PNG the image file size in bytes changes between the Android application and the .Net server side application. I have used Wireshark to trace the traffic and it suggests a malformed PNG.

```
104 6.538812    192.168.1.1 192.168.1.2 HTTP    992 POST  PostSave HTTP/1.1  (PNG)[Malformed Packet]
```

This is the Android code snippet that finds the image and converts it to a byte array.

```
inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);

Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
inputStream.close();

ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);

imageBytes = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
```

This is the Android code snippet that adds the PNG to the httpurlconnection using a dataoutputstream.

```
dataOutputStream.writeBytes(Constants.FORM_BOUNDARY +
                                "Content-Disposition: form-data; name= \"file_" + fileUpload.getAlias() + "\"; filename=\"" + fileUpload.getDisplayName() + "\"\r\nContent-Type:" + fileUpload.getMimeType() + "\r\n");

dataOutputStream.write(fileUploads.get(i).getByteArray(), 0, fileUploads.get(i).getByteArray().length);


dataOutputStream.writeBytes("\r\n");
```

This is the code that causes the exception on the .Net side

```
fileStream = File.OpenRead(file.TempFilePath)    
Image.FromStream(fileStream)
```

The .Net exception message is below.

```
{"Parameter is not valid."}
```

I can see the file in the Temp folder and it appears not to be a well formed PNG and fails to open using an image viewer.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this one myself, as seems common when sending data between Android and .Net the detail is where the mistakes are made. An extra newline character meant the image was read correctly at the server side.

```
dataOutputStream.writeBytes(Constants.FORM_BOUNDARY +
                            "Content-Disposition: form-data; name= \"file_" + fileUpload.getAlias() + "\"; filename=\"" + fileUpload.getDisplayName() + "\"\r\nContent-Type:" + fileUpload.getMimeType() + "\r\n\r\n"");
```